# Laravel 4 distant Eloquent relations

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to eager load a distant relation using Eloquent and am running into problems. There are 5 tables involved, they are *users*, *corporate_users*, *corporations* and two Sentry tables (*groups* and *users_groups*).

The tables are setup as follows:

- Users hasOne CorporateUsers (one-to-one)
- CorporateUsers belongsTo a Corporation (many-to-one)
- Users have a many-to-many relationship with *groups* through the *users_groups* pivot table.

All of these relationships work individually. Initially I could get around the distant relation problem by calling `CorporateUsers::with(array('user', 'corporations'));` because *CorporateUsers* have a direct relation with both *Users* and *Corporations*.

My problem is that I how to setup the relationship between CorporateUsers and Groups, through the pivot table *users_groups* which references *user_id* and not *corporate_user_id*? I've tried the hasManyThrough relationship but it wasn't working.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: What's an agent?  A Corporation User?

Comment: Sorry that was an error on my part, Agents and corporate users are two of the users groups, I got them confused. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use dot notation for nested relationships.  It should make your life easier.

```
CorporateUsers::with('user.groups', 'corporations')->get();
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks, this question has been open at laravel.io for almost two days now and you solved it in 5 min.